# Microsoft Graph .Net API: Shared OneDrive folder

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm getting an invalid request error for the following (Message: One of the provided arguments is not acceptable):

```
DriveRecipient[] invitees = new DriveRecipient[1];
invitees[0] = new DriveRecipient()
{
    Email = "testEmail@testdomain.com"
};

var test = await graphClient
    .Me
    .Drive
    .Root
    .ItemWithPath("/TestFolder")
    .Invite(invitees, true, sendInvitation : true, message: "Test Message")
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

I'm trying to share a folder (`root/TestFolder`) in OneDrive but am getting an invalid request error. Is it possible to share a folder this way? Or alternatively, how would I just create a shared folder, if this doesn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the [`roles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-invite?view=graph-rest-1.0#request-body) you want to apply ("read" and/or "write"):

```
var invitees = new List<DriveRecipient>();
invitees.Add(new DriveRecipient()
{
    Email = "testEmail@testdomain.com"
});

var test = await client
    .Me
    .Drive
    .Root
    .ItemWithPath("/TestFolder")
    .Invite(recipients: invitees,
            requireSignIn: true, 
            sendInvitation: true, 
            message: "Test Invite", 
            roles: new List<string>() { "Read", "Write" })
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```